# What is the keycode for keyboard rightclick?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

I want to catch the keyboard right click event. I can't able to find keycode for that. Anyone have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This can help for all keyboard buttons](https://www.w3.org/2002/09/tests/keys.html?)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input').bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
    alert('keyboard right click');
    console.log(e);
});
```

Note: this will also work for the mouse right click.

or

```
$("input").keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 93) {
        alert('rightclick');
    }
});
```

Note: keycode 93 for winmenu

You can check [this Page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/keycodes.htm) for keycodes